# Quiet the "You are manually calling a React.PropTypes"

Tags: create-react-app

I am using the latest react and I have a custom validation function that looks like this:

```
 editing: function(props, propName, componentName) {
            /*
            {
                [password/displayname/email]: {
                    form: object
                    destroying: bool
                }
            }
            */
            let prop = props[propName];

            if (prop === undefined) return; // is not isRequired

            let failobject = PropTypes.object({ [propName]:prop }, propName, componentName);
            if (failobject) return failobject;

            for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(prop)) {
                let failkey = PropTypes.oneOf(['password', 'displayname', 'email'])({ key:key }, 'key', componentName);
                if (failkey) return failkey;

                let failshape = PropTypes.shape({
                    form: PropTypes.object, // not required, as initially undefined
                    destroying: PropTypes.bool // not required, as i only set this to true when it starts to transition out
                })({ value:val }, 'value', componentName);
                if (failshape) return failshape;
            }
        }
    }).isRequired,
```

I ONLY plan to ever use this in development. React keeps yelling at me with this warning:

> "Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation
>   function for the `key` prop on `BodyProfile`. This is deprecated and
>   will not work in production with the next major version. You may be
>   seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library. See
>   fb.me/react-warning-dont-call-proptypes for details." 
>   bundle.js:11902:10

I am using create-react-app - is there anyway to tell it I am in development and not tell me this deprecation warning?